# Material-ui grid not putting any spacing

Tags: reactjs, grid, material-ui, spacing

I can't seem to figure this out. I'm trying to use the `Grid` component with Material-UI, but whenever I try there is no spacing between the elements. I tried with my own code, and then some code from a tutorial website and neither produced the desired spacing between elements.

Here is code I used:

```
<Grid container spacing={40} justify="center">
    <Grid>
      <Card>
        <Typography component='h4' variant='h4'>Manager Login</Typography>
        <Button>Login</Button>
      </Card>
    </Grid>
    <Grid>
      <Card>
        <Typography component='h4' variant='h4'>User Login</Typography>
        <Button>Login</Button>
      </Card>
    </Grid>
  </Grid>
```

[And this is what it produces](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vOEX8.png)

And because I know my code isn't the best, I also tried [this](https://reactgo.com/material-ui-react-tutorial/) tutorial from reactgo and I got the same problem.

Full code: https://pastebin.com/n6gnQN6B
Code Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/embed/interesting-mahavira-912zf

Comment: The valid values for the [Grid spacing property](https://material-ui.com/api/grid/#props) are 0-10. Since each spacing unit is 8px, this gives you up to 800px spacing. If you are looking for 40px of space then you should use a value of 5.

Comment: Perfect, solved. I knew it was me doing something dumb. Is there any reason for using values >10? The tutorial I was following from reactgo used 40.

Comment: The tutorial was probably created for v3 which used pixel spacing values with allowed values of `0, 8, 16, 24, 32, 40`. In v4, `Grid` was changed to use spacing units of 0-10 where each spacing unit is 8px.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. Thanks for your help.